# Select from list based on compound key

Tags: select

I have following student table

```
ID     Version      Name       Email
1        1         Johan        Johan@email.com
1        2         Johan 1      Johan@email.com
2        1         Saif         saif@email.com
2        2         Saif  1      saif2@email.com
2        3         Saif  4      saif1@email.com
```

I want to select student records based top version.

```
ID     Version      Name       Email
1       2          Johan 1      Johan@email.com
2       3          Saif  4      saif1@email.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key points here, are  :

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Version] DESC) AS RN
```

and

```
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here is:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
    ([ID] int, [Version] int, [Name] varchar(6), [Email] varchar(15))
;

INSERT INTO Student
    ([ID], [Version], [Name], [Email])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Johan', 'Johan@email.com'),
    (1, 2, 'Johan1', 'Johan@email.com'),
    (2, 1, 'Saif', 'saif@email.com'),
    (2, 2, 'Saif1', 'saif2@email.com'),
    (2, 3, 'Saif4', 'saif1@email.com')
;

-- select


;WITH StudentCTE AS
(
SELECT [ID], [Version], [Name], [Email]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Version] DESC) AS RN
FROM Student
)

SELECT  [ID], [Version], [Name], [Email]
FROM StudentCTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

output:

```
ID  Version Name    Email
1   2   Johan1  Johan@email.com
2   3   Saif4   saif1@email.com
```